# Trying to Implement Waiter Arbitrator Solution to Dining Philosophers in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency

I'm preparing for a programming interview and thought I should give a try implementing various solutions to Dining Philosophers Problem.

While I was able to implement Dijkstra and Tannenbaum's solution, I'm having trouble figuring out the Waiter and Arbitrator solution to the problem.

Right now, all I can think of is that there should be a Waiter class, and an Arbitrator class (this is where I implement attemptToEat() and isDoneEating() methods) while in the Waiter class I intent to implement (permissionToEat() method). All classes interact with a separate class for Forks for which I use the following code:

```
public class Fork {


private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

private final int numberAroundTable;
private boolean usedFork = false; 

public Fork(int numberAroundTable) {
    this.numberAroundTable = numberAroundTable;

}

public int getNumberAroundTable() {
    return numberAroundTable;
}



//'use' method to try pickup a fork and if successful change usedChopstick to true

public void use(){
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        usedFork = true;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        usedFork = false;
    }
}

public void putDown(){
    usedFork = false;
    semaphore.release();
}

public boolean isUsed(){
    return usedFork;
}

}
```

What should be the pseudocode for implementing a waiter and arbitrator solution if I use the methods I've thought of and what am I missing?